# How do i close the window when my turtle leaves the window

Tags: python

So I've been designing a game where You have to stay in the window, but I don't know how to make it when I leave the window the game ends. If you could help it would be great. As you can tell I am new to python so please don't judge :)

```
import turtle

points = 0

print("Welcome to Enterio!")
print("You have to use the arrow keys to finish the game!")
print("If you leave the window COMPLETLY than your lose.")
print(" ")
start = input("Start? (y/n) ")
if(start == "y"):
print("Level 1")
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("lightblue")

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("black")
player.shape("triangle")
speed = 1
while(True):
    if(points == 10):
        speed += 5
        print("Level 2")
    elif(points == 20):
        speed += 5
        print("Level 3")
    elif(points == 30):
        print("You Win!")
        end = input("")

    player.penup()
    player.forward(speed)

    def right():
        player.right(90)
    def left():
        player.left(90)
    def lvlup():
        global speed
        speed += 1
        global points
        points += 1
        if(points > 1):
            print("You have", points, "points")
        else:
            print("You have", points, "point.")

    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(left, "Left")
    turtle.onkey(right, "Right")
    turtle.onkey(lvlup, "Up")
elif(start == "n"):
    print("Ok, bye!")
    pause = input("")
```

Comment: Instruct the turtle to close the window on its way out :))

Comment: Thanks for the help! I don't exactly know how to do that though. If you could explain or give me some code that would be helpful :)

Comment: @ChocolateGames What have you tried so far? What did google tell you? SO isn't an advice forum nor a code writing service; You need to show us what you tried that isn't working so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code so you can see how it could work.

```
import turtle

pointer = turtle.Turtle() # Create a turtle.

w = turtle.window_width () # | Get our window dimensions.
h = turtle.window_height() # }

w, h = w // 2, h // 2 # Divide by two, because we start at (0, 0).

while True:
    x, y = turtle.pos() # Get x, y positions.
    if abs(x) > w or abs(y) > h: # Check if we are not outside of the window.
        turtle.bye() # Kill the turtle. ;(
    turtle.forward(5) # Move.
```

Comment: Although on this case it doesn't change much, you probably want to check x and y immediately after retrieving them (so, before doing another forward).